# How to place two div's side by side. and one at the bottom in table using css?

Tags: html, css

How to place two div's side by side. and one at the bottom using css?

Is there any way uisng display or the position property?

```html
<table class="responsive_table Append_row">
  <tr class="list_row bg_div">
    <td>
      <p class="m-0 PSS_text">1_TIME</p>

      <div class="d-flex gap-2">
        <div class="empty_div"></div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault3" id="flexRadioDefault1" checked />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                          ON
                        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault4" id="flexRadioDefault2" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                          YES
                        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <br/>
    <td class="dropdown_list">
      <select class="form-select select_aro select_options" id="choice" style="width:150% ; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <option value="" disabled selected>
          HH:MM/MM±Dusk/MM±Dawn
        </option>
        <option>H1</option>
        <option>H2</option>
        <option>H3</option>
        <option>H4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to place two div's side by side. and one at the bottom using css?

Is there any way uisng display or the position property?

Comment: you can do it using flex or grid

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D In the table i have two td's. where i want to display two first td side by side and dropdown bottom of it.

Comment: check out the answer

Comment: in table if you want to extend a cell to take more than one cell you can use colspan and rowspan attributes

Comment: your code makes absolutely no sense.  Shows us a sketch diagram of what you will like to achieve

Comment: Why does your question say "using CSS" when you are using tables? It's easy to do what you want to do using only table formatting, without CSS. Do you want to format a table using CSS instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box. Looking at your code I don't know which `div` elements you want to reposition. Here's an example of the layout you were wanting to achieve.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  
}

.boxA {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.boxB {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="boxA">box1</div>
  <div class="boxA">box2</div>
</div>
<div class="boxB">box3</div>
```

Comment: Is that possible using table. and td,tr

Comment: Well, changing from `display: table` to `display:flex` is possible. Sorry if I misunderstood your question as I thought you were only talking about `div` elements you wanted to rearrange. Which specific elements in your code do you want to change?

Comment: If u can look at my code, In the table i have two td's. where i want to display two first td side by side and dropdown bottom of it. Any suggestions as per my code will be helpful.

Comment: I need a little more clarity then. I only see two `td` elements in the code. So you want the content of the first `td` to be side-by-side, and the second `<td class="dropdown_list">` is underneath?

Answer (score 0):

This is the flex approach.

```
  <html>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="side-by-side">
 <div>Left</div>
<div>Right</div>
</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Css is

```
div{
width:100px;
background-color:red;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
.side-by-side{
display:flex;
}
```

you can also achieve this using grid.

Comment: if you want to learn about grid and flex i would recommend the website css-tricks